# Display notification on lockscreen

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I am creating an alarm clock application and I would like to show alarm icon with time of next alarm on lock screen.
Could you help me, how it is possible to show alarm notification on locksreen ?

This is what I want, but the notification is from android alarm clock : http://i42.tinypic.com/w9fyvd.jpg

I found this tutorial, but it can be used only on Android 4.2 or newer.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling App Widgets on the Lockscreen is the new feature on android 4.2. So you can't create icon on bulid-in lockscreen below android 4.2, unless you have a custom lockscreen application.

You may try to put the alarm notification(suggest the date of next alarm,replace the alarm icon) on notification bar.This can also show the next alarm date on lockscreen.
:-)